# Convert double to string, keep format - C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, numbers, converters

*Hi all. I have a double number (Ex: 0.000006). I want convert it to string type. But result is "6E-06". I dont want it, i want 0.000006".Thanks you so much*

```
double a = 0.000006; 
string resultString = a.toString();
```

I don't know many number after "." character

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's simple that if you want to show a number as exactly as what it looks, we can cast it to `decimal` and use the default `ToString()` like this:

```
var s = ((decimal)yourNumber).ToString();
//if yourNumber = 0.00000000000000000000000006
//just append the M after it:
var s = (0.00000000000000000000000006M).ToString();
```

Comment: Thanks bro, this is my waiting answer, i will change double type to decimal.Thanks you again

Comment: @Futureman No, you don't need to change its `declaring type`, you just to need to cast it to `decimal` and perform `ToString()` on it as my code shows. After that, `yourNumber` is still type of `double`.

Comment: Oh, Sorry i dont read carefully your comment.Thanks you so much :)

Answer (score 4):

Please check this article and find the format which suits your needs: http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-double/

Looks like this one is good enough:

```
String.Format("{0:0.00}", 123.4567);
```

Comment: Thanks but i want to keep format. Your code result is "123.46"

Answer (score 3):

Use [String.Format()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fht0f5be.aspx) with the [format specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s8s7t687%28VS.71%29.aspx).

```
double a = 0.000006;
string formatted = String.Format("{0:F6}", a);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with the [Roundtrip 'R' format specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx?ppud=4#RFormatString):

```
double a = 0.000006;
string resultString = a.ToString("R");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
            Double Rate_USD = Convert.ToDouble(txtRateUsd.Text);
            string Rate_USD = txtRateUsd.Text;
```

Comment: Code only answers are not good answers, try adding a few lines explaining what the problem was and how your code fixes it